# vb.net Web Server linq to sql returns

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

My last question was not clear. Im trying to make a web service in VB.net is their a way that i can return the results that i get from LINQ.  ie "return objreturnLINQResults"
 I have tryed to set my Public Function GetAlarmsByGUIS(ByVal DeptGUID As String, ByVal IdNumber As String) As Linq.DataContext . i just keep getting errors. help please.

```
Public Function GetAlarmsByGUIS(ByVal DeptGUID As String, ByVal IdNumber As String) As Linq.DataContext
    Dim lqAlarms As New linqAlarmDumpDataContext
    Dim Temp As String = ""
    Dim n As Integer = 0
    Dim GetAlrms = From r In lqAlarms.AlarmDrops _
                   Where r.DeptGUID = DeptGUID And Not r.AlarmsHandled.Contains(IdNumber) _
                   Order By r.TimeDate Descending _
                   Select r


    Return GetAlrms
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can't create web service's method which returns DataContext object.Return values and input parameters of Web service methods must be serializable through the XmlSerializer class. DataContext is not serializable

2) The simplest way to avoid errors it is return an array of serializable objects. Like this Return GetAlrms.ToArray();

Comment: OK so if i return an array what do i set the Function  as ? Ex 
Public Function GetAlarmsByGUIS(ByVal DeptGUID As String, ByVal IdNumber As String) As Array it just errors out as well. sorry for being the dum questions but im new to web services.

Comment: You have to write like this - Public Function GetAlarmsByGUIS(ByVal DeptGUID As String, ByVal IdNumber As String) As AlarmDrop[]. I am not sure about AlarmDrop type, it must be type of r - variable from linq query. Good luck!